# Gensim Doc2Vec.infer_vector() equivalent in KeyedVector

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

I have a working app using `doc2vec` from [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html). I know the [`KeyedVector`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) is now the recommended approach, and trying to port over however I am not sure what is the equivalent method for the `infer_vector` method in `Doc2Vec`?

Or better put, how do I obtain a document vector for an entire document using the `KeyedVector` model to write to my Annoy model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`KeyedVectors`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html) doesn't replace `Doc2Vec`, it's a storage and index system for word vectors:

> Word vector storage and similarity look-ups. Common code independent
>   of the way the vectors are trained(Word2Vec, FastText, WordRank,
>   VarEmbed etc)
>
> The word vectors are considered read-only in this class.

This class doesn't know anything about tagged documents and it can't implement `infer_vector` or an equivalent because this procedure requires training and the idea of `KeyedVectors` is to abstract from the training method.

Comment: so is the recommended route to continue with the Doc2Vec class? Sorry, the documentation is sparse (pardon the pun) and with the multiple versions it is confusing.

Comment: @Santino so far I don't see any signs that you should switch, so you can continue to use doc2vec